# For each sub-tree in an AST tree, create a corresponding list using Python

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Recently, I was working on a project of detecting plagiarism in python code. I learned an interesting method from an literature (https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221554617). In this article, authors created a characteristic vector which is a numerical approximation of a particular sub-tree. Each vector consists of the sum of the node’s children’s vectors.

[characteristic vectors with an AST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMbGT.png)

To do this, I need to create a 8-length list for each sub-tree in order to record information. **The problem is that there must be a correspondence between the list and the subtree, otherwise it will be meaningless.** Using a dictionary may not be a good way because I need to traverse the tree.

Ideally I want to get a new storage structure like **newnode** which has attributes like below:

```
#Points to the current node(or sub-tree)
newnode.node

#The list corresponding to the node
newnode.vector
```

Here is my attempt (you can ignore if you want):

```
import ast
import numpy as np


class NewNode:
    def __init__(self, node):
        self.node = node
        self.vector = np.zeros(8)


class Operation(ast.NodeTransformer):

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        ast.NodeTransformer.generic_visit(self, node)
        new_node = NewNode(node)
        print(type(node).__name__)
        # the code below is an example of record ast.Store node-type
        if isinstance(new_node.node, ast.Store):
            new_node.vector[5] += 1


source = \
    """
a = 10
b = "test"
print(a)
    """
node = ast.parse(source)
k = Operation()
k.generic_visit(node)
```

Comment: I'm not sure there is a trivial way to, given a node, just read a list of children nodes. I think the format differs between different node types but I could be wrong.  You may need to make a subclass of each node type so that each has a function to visit (calculate the vector) for all it's direct children (so it will do it recursively)

Comment: never mind my above comment, [`ast.iter_child_nodes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.iter_child_nodes) is very much a thing and I feel silly ever thinking it wouldn't be.  By the way, your `generic_visit` needs to `return node` in order to not destroy the entire ast structure after visiting stuff.

Answer (score 2):

you are allowed to add fields to the nodes in place, that way you can just do `node.vector = ...` right on the node itself and then after visiting all nodes in the tree will have said vector with what ever logic you want applied.  Note that `generic_visit` needs to `return node` or the visiter breaks stuff (returning nothing assumes you want to just destroy that subtree)

```
import ast
import numpy as np

characteristics_map = {
    # can just store the array for each node type, might be easier than case logic.
    ast.Store: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
}

class Operation(ast.NodeTransformer):

    def generic_visit(self, node):
        # you are allowed to add arbitrary fields to python objects
        node.vector = np.zeros(8)
        ast.NodeTransformer.generic_visit(self, node)
        for a in ast.iter_child_nodes(node):
            # this node will be sum of all children nodes
            # as well as case logic below.
            node.vector += a.vector

        if type(node) in characteristics_map:
            node.vector += np.array(characteristics_map[type(node)])
        return node


source = \
    """
a = 10
b = "test"
print(a)
    """
node = ast.parse(source)
k = Operation()
k.generic_visit(node)
# there are 2 stores so the 5th element has a value of 2
print(node.vector)
```